# Flex 3: Convert Plain text editor to Rich Text Editor

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex3

Trying to save htmlText from a RichTextEditor back to an Oracle database. From what I've gathered searching all afternoon, I shouldn't need to change my database type from a varchar2 to a blob, but I do need to change something in the Flex/Java side to persist the htmlText to the database, right? I found a couple of posts on a few different blogs talking about passing htmlText back and forth, but it wasn't with a database, it was just through a string array.

Currently I have a RichTextEditor on my UI, however it only saves plain text to my backend. What would need to be added or changed to convert that to htmlText? Do I need to use the TextConverter and cast the result to a string and then save that?

Thanks

Ian

Edit. Here is the code

Here is my rich text box code

```
<mx:RichTextEditor id="messageText" width="750" height="225"
                               change="{modelLocator.notification.message.message = messageText.text; validateChange()}"
                               enabled="{inputEnabled}"
                               htmlText="{modelLocator.notification.message.message}"
                               textAlign="left"/>
```

I'm not sure how or if I need to convert the text that is coming out of the htmlText and going into my message.text string. I will spend some more time buried in this Flex 4 in Action book and see if I can find anything helpful.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you've already tried? It might help us see what could be wrong.

Comment: I've used the debugger and inspected htmlText and can see that it is formatted with all the <html> tags, why is that not going into my message text?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the source code of your Rich Text Editor (Little Bit):

[Source Code](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/1081/1/Creating-simple-WYSIWYG-editor-with-AS3-Flex/Page1.html) | [Demo of Rich Text Editor](http://krasimirtsonev.com/files/wysiwyg/bin/)